# How to solve Captchas with Python Capmonster

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha

I am using Python selenium chromedriver and I want to add Capmonster to my code. Basically if my Code gets the URL, a ReCaptcha appears and I want to get it solved.

My Code

```
from threading import Thread
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import os


chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\yvesb\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600') # optional
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)


def test(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        driver.save_screenshot('C:\\Users\\yvesb\\Downloads\\headless_chrome_test7.png')
    finally:
        print("screenshot done")

url = "https://www.snipes.com/login"
Thread(target=test, args=(driver, url)).start()
```

And when it gets the URL a ReCaptcha appears, which I want to get solved with my Capmonster Key.

Comment: ReCaptcha was created to prevent bots. If you own the site, see [the docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do) on how to bypass it in test environments. If you don't, stop trying to pass ReCaptcha.

Comment: u can check this out maybe it could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67107542/15336413

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try this library I've developed some time ago. If you have a set of labelled captchas that service would fit you. Take a look: https://github.com/punkerpunker/captcha_solver

In README there is a section "Train model on external data" that you might be interested in.